# Can I get .config file from vmlinuz file?

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, configuration

I am using Arch Linux with a custom kernel stored as `/boot/vmlinuz-linux1`. Some features I would like to have don't work in it, but there is also a `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` kernel where those features work. How can I retrieve the `.config` kernel configuration file from the second `vmlinuz` file in order to compare it with the configuration of the first kernel in a text editor?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958192/how-to-get-the-config-from-a-linux-kernel-image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, extracting the `.config` configuration file from a kernel is possible only if you've compiled it with the configuration option `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` (available in the configuration menu as entry `General setup > Kernel .config support`). Here is the documentation of that configuration option:

```
CONFIG_IKCONFIG:                                                                                                                                                                      

This option enables the complete Linux kernel ".config" file
contents to be saved in the kernel. It provides documentation
of which kernel options are used in a running kernel or in an
on-disk kernel.  This information can be extracted from the kernel
image file with the script scripts/extract-ikconfig and used as
input to rebuild the current kernel or to build another kernel.
It can also be extracted from a running kernel by reading
/proc/config.gz if enabled (below).
```

The last sentence refers to an additional configuration option `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` which gives you access to the configuration of a running kernel through a file in the `proc` pseudo-filesystem.

If your kernel has not been compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG`, I don't think you can retrieve its configuration easily. Otherwise, it's as simple as

```
gunzip /proc/config.gz > .config
```

if `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` has been selected and you're currently running your `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` kernel, or

```
scripts/extract-ikconfig /boot/vmlinuz-linux
```

The script `extract-ikconfig` is the one available along with the kernel sources, in folder `scripts`.

Comment: Yes, I have this option enabled. So I need to extract /proc/config.gz?

Comment: Yes, if there is a file /proc/config.gz, you can do `gunzip /proc/config.gz > .config` to retrieve the configuration.

Comment: Ok, I extracted it, but it seems to be the same .config file I already have from vmlinuz-linux1...

Comment: Are you sure you're running the kernel `vmlinuz-linux`?

Comment: Now I am running `vmlinuz-linux1` . Should I reboot with another kernel and extract it there? Ok, just a moment.

Comment: Otherwise you can use the script `extract-ikconfig` on `vmlinuz-linux`. The script is in the folder `scripts` in the kernel source and is also available here: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/linux/scripts/extract-ikconfig.

Comment: Ok. I've got this .config after rebooting with second kernel. Perfect! Thank you